# unable to make toast in activity constructor

Tags: android, android-toast

I am getting an error as Null pointer exception and unable to instantiate activity when I am creating a toast in activity constructor.I want to know the reason why toasts are working in onCreate method but not in activity constructor

Comment: "I am getting an error as Null pointer exception and unable to instantiate activity when I am creating a toast in activity constructor" -- that is because you should not have an activity constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS is responsible for constructing your `Activity` classes. This is because it needs to perform some setup, including providing the `Activity` a proper base `Context`. Without this, you cannot make `Toast`s.

In general, you should avoid doing anything in the constructor of an `Activity` (and you should definitely **not** be making instances of them yourself using `new`).

Comment: is activity context constructed in activity  constructor

Comment: @deshmanth No. In general it's better not to have a constructor at all and defer any setup to `onCreate()`, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a Toast appears as a feedback to user input (say a button click) or when some external event is registerd (say a network error happend or new incoming data is available).

However, to me it sounds as though you want to show a Toast right after opening your activity, is that correct? Then you should put it in the `onCreate` method of your activity. An example Toast is made like this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You might also consider putting this call in the `onResume` method. I recommend getting familiar with [activity lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Instead of using Toasts you might also want to check out [Snackbars](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#).

Comment: I just wanted to test what happens if we use activity constructor and why it is not important